# How do I get Flymake to work for SCSS mode?

Tags: flymake

I have [flymake-sass](https://github.com/purcell/flymake-sass) working, but I can't get it to work for SCSS files. The source *looks* like it should work with SCSS, but when I try to enable it I get an error about `scss-sass-options` not being defined. After defining that as `nil` in `.emacs` it loads but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be to use [flycheck](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/) which supports SCSS out of the box.